# Why won't my req.flash work?

Tags: json, parsing, node.js, exception, try-catch

Here's a Node.js function. It works, in the sense that bad JSON data is kicked out, but it also flashes the message that it failed. Why?

```
// Create document 
app.post('/documents.:format?', loadUser, function(req, res) {

        /////////////////////////added by adam
        //tests to see if the inputed text is valid JSON data
        data = req.body.d.data;
        console.log("///////////" + data);

        try { 
            type = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(type);
        } catch (ex) { 
            console.log("bad json: "+data);
            req.flash('Nope', 'Invalid JSON');
            res.redirect('/documents');
            return;
        }

            var d = new Document(req.body.d);
            d.user_id = req.currentUser.id;
            d.save(function() {
                switch (req.params.format) {
                    case 'json':
                        res.send(d.toObject());
                        break;

                    default:
                        req.flash('info', 'Document created');
                        res.redirect('/documents');
                }
            });
```

Comment: is 'Nope'  a valid message type?  Try 'error' instead.

Comment: anything is a valid message type

Comment: Can you do a `console.log` of the `req.session` at '/documents'?

Answer (score 0):

The `catch` block contains both the error message and the 'bad JSON' logger, so they will always occur at the same time, due to the block scope.